# Correct usage of the phrase "due on"

Tags: grammar

What is the correct usage of the phrase "due on"?

For example: is the sentence "my recruitment is due on 2/2/2018" correct? 
Or is it better to use "I am to be recruited on 2/2/2018"?

Answer (score 2):

They are both okay to be honest. They are a bit formal and the second one is even more formal but there is nothing wrong with them.

**You could say either of the ones in your post above or you could say:**

*"My start date is 2/2/2018".*

*"I'm being hired on 2/2/2018 by XYZ."*

*"I'm due to start working with XYZ on 2/2/2018."*

**If it's military you could use:**

*"I'm due to start my military career on 2/2/2018."*

*"I'm being recruited by the Army on 2/2/2018."*

*"My military term starts on 2/2//2018."*